# Error code 512 while calling setUbiquitous:

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, icloud

I know this question has been asked before but so far none of the posts that I found solve my problem.

Here's my codes

```
NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:
                                     @"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent: kCloudStorageFileName];

CloudDocument *doc = [[[CloudDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage] autorelease];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
{
       NSError* error = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];
       if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous: true itemAtURL: [doc fileURL] destinationURL: ubiquitousPackage error: &error])
       {
          NSLog(@"Moved Cloud successfully");
       }
       else
       {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
       }
});
```

I'm getting error and I don't know how to fix it.
Hope someone can help me out :(

```
    Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)"
 UserInfo=0x1f82a3b0 
{NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/QR39Z776YC~com~something~testApp/Documents/cloudSavedData.doc, NSUnderlyingError=0x1f82a820 "
The operation couldn’t be completed.
```

Comment: Any particular error message, or just the 512?

Comment: I just added the error message in the post.

Comment: One cause for that error is if there's already a file in the target location with the same name-- in this case, if you already have an iCloud document named `cloudSavedData.doc`. Any chance that's the case?

Comment: I think it might be the case but I thought it will overwrite it? How can I overwrite it?

Answer (score -1):

If the file already exists you shouldn't be calling setUbiquitous on it. Use [NSFileManager isUbiquitousItemAtURL:] to determine if it's already in iCloud.